# mySQL: mysqlimport to import comma delimited file - first column = ID which is NOT in the file to be imported

Tags: mysql, import, mysqlimport

Hi Folks I am trying to import a very large file that has moisture data recorded daily per minute for 20 cities in the US.

I have 1 table that I named "cityname" and this table has 2 columns:

```
-city_ID <- INT and is the primary key which increments automatically
-city_name <- character
```

I have created another table named "citymoisture" and this table has 7 columns:

```
-city_ID <- INT and is the primary key but does NOT increment automatically
-date_holding VARCHAR(30)
-time_holding VARCHAR(30)
-open
-high
-low
-close
```

The date_holding is meant to house the date data but because the format isnt what mysql expects (i.e. it is m/d/y) I want to initially store it in this column and then convert it later (unless there is a way to convert it while the data is being imported???). Similarly the time_holding column holds the time which appears as hh:mm:ss AM (or PM). I want to only import the hh:mm:ss and leave out whether it is AM or (PM).

In any case the file that I want to import has SIX columns:

date, time, open, high, low, close.

I want to ensure that the data being imported has the correct city_ID set to match the city_ID in the 'cityname' table. So for example:

```
city_ID city_name
20      Boston 
19      Atlanta
```

So when the moisture data for Boston is imported into the citymoisture table the city_ID column is set to 20. Similarly when the data for Atlanta is imported into the citymoisture table the city_ID column is set to 19. The citymoisture table will be very large and will store the 1 minute moisture data for 20 cities going forward.

So my questions are:

1) is there a way to import the contents of the files into column 2-7 and manually specify the the value of the first column (city_ID)?

2) any way to convert dates on the fly while I import or do I have to first store the data and then convert and store to what would then be a final table.

3) same question as #2 but for the time column.

I greatly appreciate your help.

THe sample of the moisture data file appears below:

```
1/4/1999,9:31:00 AM,0.36,0.43,0.23,0.39  
1/4/1999,9:32:00 AM,0.39,0.49,0.39,0.43  
.  
.  
.
```

I'm not sure how the city_ID in the citymoisture table is going to get set. But if there was a way to do that then I can run join queries based on both tables i.e. there is one record per city per date/time.

Comment: `-city_ID <- INT and is the primary key but does NOT increment automatically` I feel like you want this to be a FK to your city table and not have it as a primary key

Comment: I believe you are right. So I created the FK to link the city_ID in the citymoisture table to that in the cityname table. But now the question is - how does mysql know what to place in this field when I try to import say moisture data for Boston? The moisture data file (comma separated) does not have a column which indicates which city_ID to set. There must be a way of telling mysql that boston data is being imported so set the city_ID for boston found in the cityname table. Any ideas?

Comment: using a select for the SET in LOAD DATA INFILE will give you the ID of the city you want from the cityname table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) should work for getting your date and time

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2001', '%m/%d/%Y');
+---------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2001', '%m/%d/%Y') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2001-01-01                            |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10:53:11 AM','%h:%i:%s %p');                                                        
+------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('10:53:11 AM','%h:%i:%s %p') |
+------------------------------------------+
| 10:53:11                                 |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

How are you going to determine what city the data for each row belongs do "manually", can you include a sample row of what the import data file looks like? Assuming somehow you have the city_ID, (replace  in code below):

It looks like you are going to want to use this: [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

if the city you wanted to insert data for is Boston from a file named 'Boston.dat', and an entry exists on your cityname table:

```
SET @c_name = 'Boston';
SET @filename = CONCAT(@c_name,'.dat');

LOAD DATA INFILE     @filename
INTO TABLE           city_moisture
(@date, @time, open, high, low, close)
SET                  city_ID=(SELECT city_ID FROM TABLE cityname WHERE city_name=@c_name),
                     date=STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%m/%d/%Y'),
                     time=STR_TO_DATE(@time, '%H:%i:%s %p');
```

Leaving off the AM PM portion of the time just sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I guess I don't necessarily have to remove the AM/PM. As long as mysql accepts the data and recognizes it as time data which I can run queries on then I am fine. I provided a sample of the moisture data file above in my original post (i edited the post). Once again thank you very much.

Comment: removing the am pm would make running queries a pain... getting both 10 am and 10 pm data when you run a query looking at 10:00:00 would be terrible. =)

Comment: Is there a function called STR_TO_TIME in mySQL? I get an error indicating that the function does not exist. I've been searching the documentation as well. 

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, you can just use STR_TO_DATE and using the formatting string with only time it will give you a time as shown in the example above.

Comment: Thank you. I had to make some adjustments i.e. added FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' and LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'....   it works wonderfully. Thank you again for all your help kriegar!

Comment: ah.. i discovered a problem. The dates in the data file are not 24-hour format. So 03:40:00 is actually 3:40 pm. When I try to run a query to extract data between 12:00:00 and 15:00:00 the data that is associated with this time period is not returned. Is there a way to force the STR_TO_DATE to convert the time to a 24-hour format?

Comment: use the %p to catch the AM PM and it will convert your time to 24 hour format. `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10:45:03 PM', '%h:%i:%s %p');` gives you `22:45:03`

Comment: @user668624 you might want to post follow up questions as a new question instead of as comments to this one.